# Angle bracket in XML regex not matching

Tags: regex, spring, apache-camel

I have a regex stored within an Apache Camel XML file:

```
<simple>${body} regex '\s*&lt;+.*'</simple>
```

I am trying to match the string:

```
&lt;?xml
```

(the first part of an encoded XML file)

i.e. literally the characters `&lt;`.

The Problem is that since this is contained in an XML file it is being treated as an encoded angle bracket and only matching `<?xml`.

Is there a way to escape this and make the match work for the encoded string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to double escape it:

```
<simple>${body} regex '\s*&amp;lt;+.*'</simple>
```